# Layout don't fit emulator

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout that works perfect in my android phone milestone but when i use the emulator it just look huge. i have try a lot of diferent configuration of emulator but nothing works. any ideas? thanks in advance.

```
<LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/fondo2" > 

      <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1">
      <TextView
          android:text=""
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:textSize="6pt"          
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="2"/>
      <TextView
          android:text="###############---------------------------###############"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:textSize="11pt" 
          android:textColor="#239874"         
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="2"/>
     <TextView
          android:text="Â¿Que Desea hacer?"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:textSize="50pt" 
          android:textColor="#63B874"         
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
     <TextView
          android:text="###############----------------------------###############"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:textSize="11pt"
          android:textColor="#239874"          
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="2"/>          
     <TextView
          android:text=""
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:textSize="11pt"
          android:textColor="#239874"          
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="2"/>             

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
          android:text=""
          android:textSize="11pt"                 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="2"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/enviarexamen" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enviar Examen"        
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:textSize="20pt"       
        android:textColor="#119f0a"        
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        >
        </Button>

    <TextView
          android:text="----"
          android:textSize="22pt"                            
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="2"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/solicitarexamen" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Solicitar Examen" 
        android:textColor="#aa0000"       
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:textSize="20pt"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
            >
         </Button>
         <TextView
          android:text=""
          android:textSize="11pt"                 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="2"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: My questions is why there is so many difference between my phone and the emulator shouldn't i be able to simulate my screen in the emulator

Comment: Have you checked the Screen resolution of the emulator and mobile

Comment: Yes, I even put a  bigger one the same result

Comment: Do not use big emulator just set resolution according to your mobile when creating emulator

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3080/discussion-between-drizzom-and-nitin)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your **layout_width** and **layout_height** parameter values. For all view you specified the **layout_width** value as **fill_parent**.So that it behaves like that. Change the layout_width value.